# Vagrant not looping through directories

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

Is there a way to get `vagrant` to loop through directories and take action on files?

I've just added this line to my Vagrantfile.

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = ".vagrant/machines/demo#{i}/virtualbox/private_key', '~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

These are the other bits of the same `Vagrantfile`

```
(1..3).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "demo#{i}" do |config|
      config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
      config.vm.box_version = "202002.04.0"
      config.vm.hostname = "demo#{i}"
      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.#{i + 10}"
      config.vm.network :public_network, bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true
      config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
      config.vm.synced_folder "demo/shared", "/vagrant/shared"
      config.vm.synced_folder "demo/dual", "/vagrant/dual"
      config.ssh.private_key_path = ".vagrant/machines/demo#{i}/virtualbox/private_key, ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "50"]
        #vb.gui = true
        vb.memory = "2096"
        vb.cpus = "2"
    end
  end

end
end
```

But running `vagrant reload` errors with 
`` * `private_key_path` file must exist: .vagrant/machines/demo1/virtualbox/private_key', '~/.ssh/id_rsa ``

Which is interesting as the path and file definitely exist.

```
pwd ; ls -R
/Users/xxx/.vagrant/machines
demo1 demo2 demo3

./demo1/virtualbox:
action_provision  action_set_name  box_meta  creator_uid  private_key  id   synced_folders

./demo2/virtualbox:
action_provision  action_set_name  box_meta  creator_uid  private_key  id   synced_folders

./demo3/virtualbox:
action_provision  action_set_name  box_meta  creator_uid  private_key  id   synced_folders
```

What I expect is for vagrant to just loop through each directory and read the files

Is there some way to get vagrant to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So I found what was wrong with it.
I just needed to add extra quotes.

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = ".vagrant/machines/demo#{i}/virtualbox/private_key, ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Becomes

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = ".vagrant/machines/demo#{i}/virtualbox/private_key", "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

And it works a charm.